# Why Model View Controller in their own namespace?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This might be a bit of a noob question, but I'm curious why the convention for MVC classes is to be in their own namespace, eg

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
```

and not

```
namespace WebApplication1
```

Is there a good syntactical reason for this or is it just to improve readability?.

Is it perfectly ok to not follow this convention and use the same namespace for the whole project?

Comment: Similar issue: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/310833/why-does-everyone-put-controllers-in-one-folder-and-views-in-another. I'm not really sure the exact reason behind that, but IMHO it is a convention to replicate logical structure with matching folder names & namespaces.

Comment: you can change the namespaces to anything you like, as long as it makes sense for you. It's purely a convention. You might find though that if your project gets big, a single namespace might start to be pain and make it harder to find stuff, categorise it or avoid naming conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use namespaces any way you like, as long as it makes sense to you.

What they've done there is simply a convention deriving from the separation of concerns part.

Are their disadvantages to this method? Well yes, separate too much and your classes become a mess with too many using statements.

If you put too much under one namespace that can also cause issues because you don't know exactly what's available to you and it makes finding anything difficult.

If your namespaces follow your folder structure then it can help keep your code nicely organised and everything is easy to find just by looking at the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but namespace are there for minimizing classes name conflicts, which if you handling middle+ projects you will encounter.

More on [Namespaces](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Sharp_Programming/Namespaces)

They also help the Intellisense display current available entities, but this is just a bonus and not the actual target of name spacing.